# Как читать формальный синтаксис?

Tags: css

Как правильно читать такую документацию? Я ничего совершенно не понимаю, какие то "[", вопросительные знаки, тильды,(en-US). Я не прошу каждый элемент расшифровать, я прошу хотя бы ссылку дать, на то как это расшифровать, и очень желательно простым языком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#summary
Собственно  нашел на английском ответ, но со словарем не трудно сопоставить всё
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]